# How to remove all lines starting with Timestamp in unix

Tags: unix, sed

I have a text file which is basically a log file. In that there are logs which starts with Timestamp and LogID  in the format -

```
timestamp=2014-08-18 23:59:48.315|logId=22fef71f-979a-46aa-81b5-432d34130c34|  ( followed by some text )

timestamp=2014-08-18 22:59:48.315|logId=22fef71f-979b-46aa-81b5-432d34130htf|  ( followed by some text )
```

I need to get rid of the timestamp and get the rest of the part.

How to use "sed" command in such case.

Comment: learning involves constructing non-ambiguous questions :-) .. If you would add an example output from the sample input, the ambiguity of you headline "remove all lines starting with Timestamp", vs your later requirement "and get the rest of the part", (which I originally read as "get rid of the rest") would be easier to understand ;-) .. Ok? good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Use `cut`:

```
cut -f 2- -d \| file
```

- `-f 2-` matches everything from 2nd field to the end of the line.
- `-d \|` sets `|` as field separator.

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's@^[^|]*|@@' file
```

- `[^|]` matches anything that's not `|`

Output:

```
logId=22fef71f-979a-46aa-81b5-432d34130c34|  ( followed by some text )
logId=22fef71f-979b-46aa-81b5-432d34130htf|  ( followed by some text )
```

Answer (score 1):

When you've got fields delimited by a single character ('|' in this case), `cut` is generally the way to go, as in konsolebox's answer. If the delimiter is not necessarily a single character (for example, any amount of white space), then `awk` is probably the answer.

However, since you asked specifically about `sed`, this will work:

```
sed 's/^[^|]*|//'
```

It substitutes (*s*) text starting at the beginning of the line (*^*) and consisting of any number of non-pipes (*[^|]**) followed by a single pipe (*|*), replacing it with nothing (the nothing between the *//*).

Comment: What if suppose the above string is something like timestamp=2014-08-18 2|logId=22fd34130c34|url=%2F2%|class=xyz|thread=abc-1355496|msg=E_TYPE=exception E_NAME=some event E_DATA={"clientTimestamp":"2014-08.588+05:30","pid":null,"prId":"T6ZWEM"} E=some error: String null does not conform to the pattern ^V.*                                     -- In this case i can remove the first two things using  cut command. But I need count the uniq number of errors.  SO problem here is that the **Client Timestamp** is giving each line as unique.. Is there anyway i can remove ClientTime stamp as well.